# How to declare a JSON string in postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql

There are many examples of json parsing in POSTGRES, which pull data from a table.  I have a raw json string handy and would like to practice using [JSON functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html).  Is it possible to do this without using tables?  Or ... what is the most straightfoward way to declare it as a variable?  Something like...

```
# Declare
foojson = "{'a':'foo', 'b':'bar'}"

# Use
jsonb_array_elements(foojson) -> 'a'
```

Basically I'd like the last line to print to console or be wrappable in a SELECT statement so I can rapidly "play" with some of these operators.

Comment: `select '{"a":"foo", "b":"bar"}'::jsonb;  {"a":"foo", "b":"bar"}`. The `jsonb_array_elements` won't work as you don't have a JSON array.

Comment: Thanks - so basically put "select" in front of the examples in the linked doc

Comment: Yes that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it directly to the function

```
select '{"a": "foo", "b": "bar"}'::jsonb ->> 'a';

select *
from jsonb_each('{"a": "foo", "b": "bar"}');

select *
from jsonb_array_elements('[{"a": "foo"}, {"b": "bar"}]');
```

Or if you want to pretend, it's part of a table:

```
with data (json_value) as (
  values 
    ('{"a": "foo", "b": "bar"}'::jsonb), 
    ('{"foo": 42, "x": 100}')
)
select e.*
from data d
  cross join jsonb_each(d.json_value) as e;


with data (json_value) as (
  values 
    ('{"a": 1, "b": "x"}'::jsonb), 
    ('{"a": 42, "b": "y"}')
)
select d.json_value ->> 'a',
       d.json_value ->> 'b'
from data d;
```

Comment: Thanks this is great.  For completeness, can you also mention how one could store the JSON variable in a declared variable so don't have to have long json string in the select statement?

Comment: @AdamHughes: SQL has no variables, so you would need PL/pgSQL for that. But you can't really display a result from within a PL/pgSQL procedure.